# How to prevent new tags being created within a Contenteditable element?

Tags: jquery, tags, element, contenteditable

```
<p contenteditable="true"></p>
<p contenteditable="true"></p>
<h1 contenteditable="true"></h1>
```

The code above consists of individual contenteditable elements rather than having the parent be contenteditable.

The problem I have is that when the user hits the Enter button in either of the contenteditable elements, it creates a new tag within that tag itself.

**Example**

The output would be:

```
<p contenteditable="true">
    <p>One</p>
    <p>Two</p>
</p>
```

The desired output would be:

```
<p contenteditable="true"></p>
<p contenteditable="true">One</p>
<p contenteditable="true">Two</p>
```

I am also using jQuery to ensure that all the elements would end up as being contenteditable:

```
setInterval(function () {
    $('p').attr('contenteditable','true');
    $('h1').attr('contenteditable','true');
},100);
```

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So you need to detect that <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key to prevent its new line behavior.

And It would also be a right time to trigger a change element!

```js
$("[contenteditable='true']").on("keydown",function(e){

  if(e.which=="13"){                      // 13 is enter key
    console.log("Enter Key!!");

    $(this).trigger("changeElement");     // Custom event here ;)
    return false;
  }
});

// Handler for our custom event: Focus on the next!
$("[contenteditable='true']").on("changeElement",function(){
  $(this).next().focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p contenteditable="true"></p>
<p contenteditable="true"></p>
<h1 contenteditable="true"></h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it seems to disable use of the enter key. After hitting the enter key, a new element isn't created outside of the one you were previously in.

Comment: I didn't see anything that should create a new element... But if you place it in the "custom event", instead of a "focus next", it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten this to work by checking if a contenteditable element contains a `p` tag after a certain interval.

If that happens to be the case, the child element will be moved in front of the parent.

```
setInterval(function () {     
    $("[contenteditable='true']").each(function() {
        finder = $(this).find("p");
        $(finder).insertAfter($(this));
        $(finder).focus();
    });    
},100);
```